# jquery ajax request to asp.net code behind not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

the ajax request is part of a larger function. I am trying to refrain from clogging up the page with code so here is the request itself:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "PubMedNewSnp.aspx/GetEdits",
                    data: "{ 'Drug':'" + drug + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (alreadyInDB) {
                        var TableName = "combo";
                        var curRow = curComboRow;
                        if (alreadyInDB) {
                            TableName = "edit";
                            curRow = curEditRow;
                            curEditRow++;
                        }
                        else {                           
                            curComboRow++;
                        }
                        do stuff...
                    }
                });
```

Here is the aspx.cs file:

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static bool GetEdits (string Drug) {
            //masterDBDataContext masterDB = new masterDBDataContext();
            bool alreadyInDB = false;

            if (Drug == "bannana")
            {
                alreadyInDB = true;
            }

            //var inTbl = (from a in masterDB.tbl_custom_SNPs_Alls
            //             join 
            //             where a.PubMedInfoId == Convert.ToInt32(curRow[0]) &&
            //                   a.DrugId == Convert.ToInt32(curRow[0])
            //             select r).ToList();

            return alreadyInDB;
        }
```

for some reason there is no response coming back. In the network tab all I see are the Request Headers and the Request payload. There is also a warning: Provisional headers are shown. Not sure what that means. Sorry if the question is phrased vaguely or not information is given. I will be glad to provide more, just not sure what else is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is your output for alreadyInDB which is in json format.

Object {d:true} or Object {d:false}

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "PubMedNewSnp.aspx/GetEdits",
                data: "{ 'Drug':'" + drug + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (alreadyInDB) { // alreadyInDB is in json format. you need to access object property.
                    var TableName = "combo";
                    var curRow = curComboRow;
                    if (alreadyInDB.d) {
                        TableName = "edit";
                        curRow = curEditRow;
                        curEditRow++;
                    }
                    else {                           
                        curComboRow++;
                    }

                }
            });
```

Hope that helps.